# Swift: How to get the size of a subview before it is being displayed?

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, autolayout

A view (a) contains a subview (b) which contains a text label.

The text label's text is set in `viewDidLoad` of view (a).
The amount of text in the label changes the size of subview (b).

I get the correct size of subview (b) only in `viewDidAppear` of view (a), but not in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

How to get the size of the subview (b) in the view controller of view (a) before it is displayed?

Update: Using auto-layout

Comment: Are you using auto layout?

Comment: Yes I use auto-layout

Comment: Then the size _is_ right `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, after you've set the text. If you doubt this, show your code and I'll run it and prove it to you.

Comment: Hey, if you post some of your code I think we'll be able to help more.

Comment: Thanks guys, I was calling `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` somewhere in a subroutine during `viewDidLoad`. Hence I was getting the wrong frame.

Answer (score 5):

The problem was that I was calling `layoutIfNeeded` during `viewDidLoad` and **before** the text label's text was set.

It forced the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` to be called immediately and not anymore thereafter.

Here is the bad sequence of calls including the subview's frame height which is 163.0 with an empty text label on the storyboard and 190.5 with the text label's text set.

```
viewDidLoad begin: frame.height: 163.0
viewDidLayoutSubviews: frame.height: 161.5 // should not be called yet
viewDidLoad end: frame.height: 161.5
viewWillAppear: frame.height: 161.5
viewDidAppear: frame.height: 190.5
```

After removing `layoutIfNeeded`:

```
viewDidLoad begin: frame.height: 163.0
viewDidLoad end: frame.height: 163.0
viewWillAppear: frame.height: 163.0
viewDidLayoutSubviews: frame.height: 190.5
viewDidAppear: frame.height: 190.5
```

Comment: Good detective work. Upvoted for solving your own problem. If I had a nickel for every time I've triggered some accidental change like this... However, I also downvoted your original question because it didn't have any code. Sorry about that.

Comment: @matt Just for anyone who is reading your comment I want to clarify that a question on SO does not require any code. This has been discussed in length on Meta SO. A question not containing any code is not a reason for downvote.

Comment: Maybe in _general_ code is not a requirement. But _your_ question needed code. You needed to show us what you were doing, and you didn't. The question as posed was thus completely unanswerable by anyone but you. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.